# How to know when the user changes the song with the Spotify API

Tags: spotify

I need to know when the user changes the song that is "currently playing".

Currently, I'm using `https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/player/currently-playing` to get the information about the song that is "currently playing". But, I need to know when it changes to the next one (not only because the song finished, but also when the user press NEXT SONG button).

My current workaround is to call the `https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/player/currently-playing` endpoint every second, but I'll be out of the rate limit if I do it very often.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are doing it right. You need to poll the https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/player/currently-playing endpoint to detect changes in the playback state.

In some scenarios it can be suitable to use [Spotify's web playback SDK](https://beta.developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-playback-sdk/quick-start/), which exposes a `player_state_changed` event. For this to work the user needs to have a premium account and the playback needs to happen on the device created by the SDK.