# Getting a request or notification when changing a track in Spotify

Tags: spotify

I want to write a program that writes the music name to a social network status. When changing a track in Spotify, I can get the name of the music, but I don't know how to get a notification when changing music.

How do I get a callback when changing a track in Spotify's API?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to know when the user changes the song with the Spotify API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48760545/how-to-know-when-the-user-changes-the-song-with-the-spotify-api)

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use the [Web Playback SDK](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-playback-sdk/reference/#event-player-state-changed) with **player-state-changed** to get these events, but this will depend on what you are going to write your programme in but it might help to look at this and see if it does what you need